# Is @DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey attribute always incremental?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Dynamodb Table with an attribute say id(unique value) which is a Range key and it should always be an incremental value. Using DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey will solve my requirement?

Answer (score 1):

No. auto-generated-keys get a UUID value which is a unique *random* string (e.g., `0674e9df-0059-4f71-a172-6e2dcb32a92d`)

Specifically, the [Java Doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey.html) says the following:

> Only String typed keys can be auto generated, and are given a random UUID.